# Why is it so hard to forget an information represented in a procedural memory

Tags: psychology, cognitive

It is relatively easy to forget an information in declarative memory but its hard to forget behavioural habits such as driving car, cycling etc. These memories are both long-term memory but why is it so hard to forget behavioural habits?